# In MAC 10.10.5 MyApp crashes

Tags: objective-c, macos, crash, crash-reports, crash-dumps

MyApp has crashed and I have collected the below crash log from that MAC book. As it is mentioned the application crashed at thread 3, I could not able to figure out what has happened,
I was suspecting it could be because of a NSTimer Lock and tryLock, but not sure how to figure it out. Crash is not happening with all MAC book but only to a certain set of users all of them are just migrated to MAC 10.10.5. But I have also other MAC book which has MAC 10.10.5 in which MyApp is running perfectly.
can anyone help me out to find the problem?

If i looked at the code at [AppMainController sendPacketForLoginStatus] + 1644
it is just a comment line just after the curly brace { starting of an else{}

```
if 
...
else  
{
<< line no: 1644>> // Change the status icon if necessary when losing the focus
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showClickStatusIconWhenLoseFocusInThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];  
...



Crash log:


Process:               MyAppAgent [581]
Path:                  /Applications/MyAppAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAppAgent
Identifier:            com.Mycmp.MyApp.MyAppAgent
Version:               1.0.0.1
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           MyAppAgent [581]
User ID:               501
Date/Time:             2015-09-08 10:32:09.940 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
Crashed Thread:        3

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000022b0dd78


....
Thread 3 Crashed:

0   com.Mycmp.MyApp.MyAppAgent         0x00012a74 -[AppMainController sendPacketForLoginStatus] + 1644
1   com.Mycmp.MyApp.MyAppAgent         0x0001012c -[AppMainController timerQueryDiscovery:] + 1726
2   com.apple.Foundation           0x943ba76f __NSFireTimer + 119
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x90653006 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x90652ab4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1316
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x906ce54f __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 351
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x9060a531 __CFRunLoopRun + 2081
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x90609aa6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 390
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x9060990b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
9   com.apple.Foundation           0x944043ea -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 305
10  com.apple.Foundation           0x944847fa -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
11  com.Mycmp.MyApp.MyAppAgent         0x00002ff0 -[AppMainController threadDiscovery:] + 360
12  com.apple.Foundation           0x943acb8d -[NSThread main] + 45
13  com.apple.Foundation           0x943ac936 __NSThread__main__ + 1538
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x9abfcc25 _pthread_body + 138
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x9abfcb9b _pthread_start + 162
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x9abf9e32 thread_start + 34
```

Comment: Have you asked Google about 'NSTimer tryLock'?

Comment: Can you explain me bit more, sorry i'm new for this

Comment: I have checked out "NSTimer tryLock", is there any point you want to highlight in it?